# footer aligns on upper div

Tags: php, html, css

I've been working on the main content of my webpage, the main content CSS class .management_wrapper width is set to 80%, on the other hand, footer's width was set to 100%. why does my footer appears the same width as the main content? can't figure this out.

HTML:

```
<div class="management_wrapper">
   <!-- 1st row-->
   <?php       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM management limit 0,2");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $name = $row['name'];
      $nposition = $row['position'];
      $img =$row['img']

      ?>      
   <center>
   <div id="info">
      <h3><?php echo $name; ?></h3>
   </div>
   <div class="list_box">
      <center> 
         <img id="img_size" src="images/main/<?php echo $img; ?>">
      </center>
   </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
<div id="footer">
   <span >
      <center>
      Copyright &copy; 2016. All rights reserved. 
   </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.management_wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: beige;
    padding-left: 1%;
}
#footer {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    margin-top: auto;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to add a Jsfiddle demo ?.

Comment: it is probably because, your footer is inside the management_wrapper tag, try to bring the footer out of your wrapper, and use left:0, right:0, bottom:0 and position absolute or fixed

Comment: Could you please post your HTML code

Comment: i updated the code with the html. kindly check it ty

Comment: please post your rendered html from browser, not your PHP code, I presume somewhere you are not closing your tags properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've corrected your code, [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8LfLumf/)

The issue was with your html tags, some was not closed.

HTML :

```
<div class="management_wrapper"> 
  <div id="info">
      <h3>name</h3>   
   </div>          
  <div class="list_box">      
    <center> 
      <img id="img_size" src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1">
    </center>   
  </div>     
</div>

<div id="footer">
   <span >
      <center>
      Copyright &copy; 2016. All rights reserved. </center>
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close your `center` tags.

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxb5hrra/)

So, your code with your PHP(server-side) code, would look like this:

```
<div class="management_wrapper">
   <!-- 1st row-->
   <?php       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM management limit 0,2");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $name = $row['name'];
      $nposition = $row['position'];
      $img =$row['img']

      ?>      
   <center>
   <div id="info">
      <h3><?php echo $name; ?></h3>
   </div>
   <div class="list_box">
      <center> 
         <img id="img_size" src="images/main/<?php echo $img; ?>">
      </center>
   </div>
   </center>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
<div id="footer">
   <span >
      <center>
        Copyright &copy; 2016. All rights reserved. 
      </center>
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because you have opened some tags without closing it I fixed it and here is a [js fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1uahg4ra/)

You used `center` tag twice without closing it I just added `</center>`
so your code become

```
 <div class="management_wrapper">
    <!-- 1st row-->

  <center>    
     <div id="info">
       <h3>John Doe</h3>
     </div>          
   <div class="list_box">      
     <center> 
       <img id="img_size" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
     </center>   
   </div>      

  </center>
</div>

 <div id="footer">
   <span > <center> Copyright &copy; 2016. All rights reserved.    </center></span>
 </div>
```

I suggest not to use `center` tag as is deprecated, you can use `text-align:center;` instead